# Adding event handler to ItemsControl items in template inside separate ResourceDictionary file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone

I have a phone application page (Main.xaml) which contains an `ItemsControl` and a data template for its items.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <local:MainItemsViewModel x:Key="mainItems" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <Grid Tap="Item_Tap"> 
            <!--....--> 
        </Grid>  
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>   

<!--...a lot of xaml...-->

<ItemsControl
       x:Name="MainCanvas"
       DataContext="{StaticResource mapItems}"
       ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Buttons}"
       ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}">
       <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  <Canvas Width="4000" Height="4000" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

As shown above, DataTemplate has an event handler which is defined in code-behind file (MainPage.xaml.cs):

```
private void Item_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e) 
{
     FrameworkElement fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
     //working with fe...

     ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true; 
     e.Handled = true;
}
```

And everything works perfect. But I want to move the data template to a separate ResourceDictionary file (ResDict.xaml).  Sure I get an error since Item_Tap event handler couldn't be fired now.  Is it possible to include an event handler in ResourceDictionary which would call Item_Tap method?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. May be it's not the best one but it works for me.
In page constructor I added an event handler for a LayoutUpdate event:

```
MainCanvas.LayoutUpdated += MainCanvas_LayoutUpdated;
```

In this event handler (MainCanvas_LayoutUpdated) I call a method that contains the code bellow:

```
foreach (var item in MainCanvas.Items)
{
        DependencyObject icg = MainCanvas.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
        (icg as FrameworkElement).Tap += MainItem_Tap;
}
```

It binds event handlers for all items in the ItemsControl (MainCanvas) after its itemsource changes and items are shown at a Canvas.

May be it will be helpfull for someone. Thanks!